# Selecting Records Where Value in One Field is the Same As or Later than Value in Another Field

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a large table called uk that includes fields called CurrTime and EvName.

Using the following query (extract below) I create a new field called StartTime that extracts the time from EvName (which is a MEDIUMTEXT field). I want to now select only the records where CurrTime is the same as or later than StartTime.

I am new to MySQL and don't even know where to start with this. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', 1), ' ', -1), ":", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', -1), ' ', 1)) AS StartTime
FROM uk;
```

Query result:

| CurrTime | EvName | StartTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01 17:39:29 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-06-01 17:39:17 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-06-01 17:45:39 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-06-01 17:37:51 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-06-01 17:48:03 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-01-01 12:47:54 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:51:15 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:51:12 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:55:02 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:41:29 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:52:29 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:57:56 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |

Desired result:

| CurrTime | EvName | StartTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01 17:45:39 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-06-01 17:48:03 | Corby 1st Jun - 17:45 | 17:45 |
| 2022-01-01 12:55:02 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |
| 2022-01-01 12:57:56 | Froom 1st Jan - 12:55 | 12:55 |

Comment: EvName does not contain a year and if you don't extract the month then a later datetime containing an earlier time element should be included?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I'm using 8.0. Thanks

Comment: @P.Salmon CurrTime is always the same day as StartTime. Thanks

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: there is some information not visible,, why there are two group for Corby 1st Jun - 17:45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function and compare.
Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM uk
WHERE
   TIME(CurrTime) >= TIME(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', 1), ' ', -1), ":", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', -1), ' ', 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating the extraction of `StartTime`.
You can do it simply like:

```
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, '-', -1))
```

and the query that you want would be:

```
SELECT *, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, '-', -1)) AS StartTime
FROM uk
WHERE TIME(CurrTime) >= TIME(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, '-', -1)));
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_QX2RiJi).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time()` to get the expected data :

```
With cte as (
  SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', 1), ' ', -1), ":", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(EvName, ':', -1), ' ', 1)) AS StartTime  
    FROM uk
)
select *
from cte
where TIME(CurrTime) > time(StartTime);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OYjmlvRu)